# Getting Android SDK Tools to work on Raspberry PI

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, android-sdk-tools

I am currently attempting to start developing for Android on the Raspberry PI 2. I have already ruled out the posibility of using an IDE such as Eclipse or Android Studios (yes I know the RPI isn't even meant to be able to run it) so I am now looking at developing from the command line.

What I have so far:

- An arm ported `adb`
- Ant tools ( & pand tools )

Now all I need to have is the `android` executable which is contained in the stand-alone SDK. I have downloaded it from this [source](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) (`android-studio-ide-135.1641136-linux.zip`). However, when I try to run the `android` executable in the command line I get the following error:

```
SWT folder '/home/pi/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/arm' does not exist.
Please export ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
```

when I run any command from the `android` file.

I have no idea what to do or how to fix it as I am a complete noob when it comes to the RPI and anything with Linux in general. Any pointers as to how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: would you mind sharing the arm version of adb somewhere ?

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=32587647&postcount=38 contains the adb binary for Raspberry Pi. I've downloaded, put the adb binary in /usr/bin on a Pi2 and it's looking good.

Comment: @HughBarnard are you talking about adbarmv6\mypart\adb file? If yes then it is not working. Do we have to copy something else as well?

Comment: How did you get **An arm ported adb**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky see Hugh Barnard's comment

Comment: How do I setup the adb?

Comment: Can you please make a video describing how to do this please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you have to look in your /usr/share/java folder, for the file swt.jar 
If that doesn't work, try:

```
sudo apt-get install libswt-gtk-3-java
```

Which will put `swt-gtk-3.8.0.jar` in the `/usr/share/java` folder.

Create the folder `/home/pi/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/arm`

Then, copy whichever file you chose, (`swt-gtk-3.8.0.jar`, or `swt.jar`) and place it in your `/home/pi/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/arm` folder. This worked for me, and I hope it will also work for you.

Comment: Note: I also had to `sudo apt-get install libswt-cairo-gtk-3-jni` as well for Rasp Pi 3 on Raspbian