# android sdk not working on ubuntu Raspberry Pi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

Hi I am trying to install android sdk in  raspberry PI and getting issues, I am using raspberry PI [arm,ubuntu mate/kali linux].
1.i have downloaded the android sdk tool and java
2.I have set the JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME & path

my requirement is like I just want to open the sdk manager GUI and rund the adb commands. I will not using it for development.

please share your thoughts

Comment: "getting issues:" is very broad statement. If it is guess game, you would get 100s of answers. If you want to clear answer, your question should have clear problem statement.

Comment: See: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44005/how-to-install-android-debug-bridge-adb-on-raspberry-pi and http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15160/can-i-develop-android-apps-on-my-raspberry-pi and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551497/getting-android-sdk-tools-to-work-on-raspberry-pi